# ListView with Custom extended BaseAdapter not showing with SherlockFragment, need hints or suggestions

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I am new to android programming and I seem to have come at a stand still for several days now. I am having trouble finding a solution to my problem and tried many different solutions without success. As the title suggests, my code runs successfully but the ListView does not show up on the selected Tabs. Any suggestions of tips would be helpful.

ItemGuide.Java ------------------------------------

```
package com.example.alzuni_project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class ItemGuide extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.leathertab_image), LeatherTab.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.leathertab_image), SilverTab.class, null);

}
}
```

---

LeatherTab.java --------------------------------------------------------------

```
package com.example.alzuni_project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class LeatherTab extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leather_fragment, container, false); //Fragment Layout inflated
    TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.boxtest);//TextView for layout testing
    text.setText("Hello");
    ListView leather_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.leather_list); // List is initialized
    leather_listview.setAdapter(new LeatherAdapter(getActivity())); //Custom list adapter passes Context

    return view;

}
}
```

---

LeatherAdapter.java ------------------------------------------------------

```
package com.example.alzuni_project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

class LeatherAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context context;
public LeatherAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.leather_list_titles);
    String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.leather_list_description);
    int[] images = {R.drawable.belt, R.drawable.wallet, R.drawable.coincase};

    for (int i=0;i<images.length;i++) //Was originally 3
    {
        new SingleRow(titles[i], descriptions[i], images[i]);
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leather_title);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leather_description);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.leather_icon);

    SingleRow temp = list.get(position);

    title.setText(temp.title);
    description.setText(temp.description);
    image.setImageResource(temp.image);

    return row;//returns the rootView of single_row.xml
}
}
```

---

leatherfragment.xml ------------------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/boxtest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCDDFF" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/leather_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/boxtest" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

SingleRow.java -----------------------------------------------------

```
package com.example.alzuni_project;

class SingleRow {

String title;
String description;
int image;

SingleRow(String title, String description, int image) {
    this.title=title;
    this.description=description;
    this.image=image;
}
}
```

---

single_row.xml ---------------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/leather_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leather_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/leather_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leather_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/leather_icon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/leather_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/leather_title"
    android:background="#CCDDFF" />
```

Comment: Move you list initialisation logic to onActivityCreated() callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list seems empty , try this in  your LeatherAdapter:

```
 list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i],descriptions[i], images[i]));
```

Inside the for loop .

Comment: That solved my problem. I was looking at the Adapter for a long time as I had narrowed it down to there. Thank you very much.